# More efficient way to calculate NPV in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, performance, coding-efficiency

I'm looking to write a function similar to Microsoft's NPV function with a few key differences:

1. It starts at time period 0 (meaning the first value is not discounted)
2. It allows an array for the discount rate to account for rate changes over time

The function I've written is below, however, it is incredibly inefficient. It is taking me minutes to save a file - so I need a new approach, but I can't see a way to do batch calculations in VBA. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Public Function NPV_UDF(disc_rng As Range, disc_rate As Variant)
'disc_rng - range of cash flows to be discounted and summed
'disc_rate - discount rate, can either be a single value, or a range of rates matched to the range of cash flows

    'range_NPV will be the running sum of the discounted cash flows
    range_NPV = 0

    'If the disc_rate is a range larger than 1 cell, check to make 
    'sure it matches the dimension of the cash flow range (disc_rng)
    If TypeName(disc_rate) = "Range" Then

        If disc_rate.Columns.Count > 1 Then

            If disc_rate.Columns.Count <> disc_rng.Columns.Count Then
                NPV_UDF = -1
                Exit Function
            End If
            'iterate over the cash flows (disc_rng), discount and update total
            For col_idx = 1 To disc_rng.Columns.Count Step 1

                range_NPV = range_NPV + (disc_rng.Cells(1, col_idx).Value / ((1 + disc_rate.Cells(1, col_idx).Value) ^ (col_idx - 1)))

            Next

        Else
            'In this conditional only a single discount rate value was specified
            'iteration will only be over the cash flows range (disc_rng) and
            'the discount rate value will remain constant
            For col_idx = 1 To disc_rng.Columns.Count Step 1

                range_NPV = range_NPV + (disc_rng.Cells(1, col_idx).Value / ((1 + disc_rate.Value) ^ (col_idx - 1)))

            Next

        End If

    Else
        'In this conditional, the discount rate (disc_rate) was some other type than a range (e.g., a hard-coded number was entered)
        'as such the same approach is taken where the discount rate 
        'is held constant and the function discounts the cash flows and totals them 
        For col_idx = 1 To disc_rng.Columns.Count Step 1

             range_NPV = range_NPV + (disc_rng.Cells(1, col_idx).Value / ((1 + disc_rate) ^ (col_idx - 1)))

         Next

     End If

     NPV_UDF = range_NPV 
End Function`
```

Comment: Not sure what is going on in there but can you use Evaluate and maybe FormulaArray?

Comment: I updated the question with commentary and fixed some of the formatting issues for directly copying and pasting - hope that makes it more clear. 

How would I use Evaluate and FormulaArray? Can you explain why they would be more efficient? New to VBA, my hunch is there is some way to do batch calcs like in python/pandas

Comment: Evaluate function on a range object can be away to do a “batch” calculation. I would have to spend time working out what is going on above first to see if possible. Tomorrow would be earliest for me. However, there are many great regular users on here who will probably be able to help you out.

Comment: For multi-cell input parameters it will be faster to read each range into an array and then run your calculations on the array than to access each cell individually on the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and look up some examples of this, if know some good ones I'd appreciate it. Do you have a sense of roughly how much faster it would be? Very interested to understand runtime mechanics in VBA

Comment: What's the typical size of your input ranges ?

Comment: ...some sample input data would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the Excel VBA function NPV by inputting values for periods 1 thru n and the discount rate. Then add the value for period 0, which would be undiscounted. An insignificantly small negative number may be needed for the last period to satisfy requirements of the function.

NPV(rate, values( ))
The NPV function has these named arguments:
Part    Description
***rate Required. Double specifying discount rate over the length of the period,
expressed as a decimal.
***values( )    Required. Array of Double specifying cash flow values. The array must
contain at least one negative value (a payment) and one positive value (a
receipt).